# data not being passed back from angularjs factory

Tags: angularjs

I created a factory to retrieve a json file. I do see that object being outputted in my console after the call but the data does not show up in my view. Am I not calling the factory correctly in my controller?

Here is my app:

```
var tools = angular.module("tools", [])

tools.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'about.html',
        controller: 'AboutController'
    });




    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    })

});

tools.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, fetchData) {

    $scope.record = fetchData.getData();
    $scope.clearSearch = function () {
        $scope.search = "";
        $scope.name2 = "";
    }
    $scope.name2 = "";
    $scope.search = "";



});


tools.controller("AboutController", function ($scope) {
    //nothing yet
});



tools.factory('fetchData', function ($http) {
    return {
        getData: function () {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'list.json'
            }).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            });
        }
    }


});
```

Comment: We would need to see your view to answer this question thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

The `$http` call is asynchronous (as are all AJAX requests), so the`return` statement in your callback isn't actually returning it data to your controller.  You'll either want to look into using [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource), which can work almost as you've written it, or pass a callback to `getData` like:

In your Controller:

```
fetchData.getData(function (data) {
    $scope.record = data;
});
```

In your Service:

```
tools.factory('fetchData', function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function(cb) {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'list.json'}).success(cb);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Big Thanks! Can you quickly show me the syntax if I were to change it over to using the $resource?

Comment: @SunnyDay Not quickly unfortunately -- it requires you have a proper REST service on your server (which you may not currently have).  You can watch this presentation... they demonstrate it at 36:00 -- parleys.com/play/5148922b0364bc17fc56c91b/about

Comment: Sorry, just curious but one other question - what is the purpose of passing in cb into getdata() and success()?

Comment: The callback passed in tells angular what to do with the data returned  once the request has completed.

Comment: @SunnyDay What Jonathan said. :)  when getData gets cb (short for callback) it's just a pointer to a function, which is exactly what the success method of $http is expecting.